# How to add new language to language pick list in user object

Tags: custom-object, user, customization, translation

I want to add multiple languages to my application.When user register,user  need to select locale language.For that I want to add some more languages for Language pick list in user object.I enable translating setting for all countries,I get Locale but Language didn't get.  How can I add some more languages to  this pick list?

Answer (score 1):

The list of languages shown in the drop-down are the only languages salesforce currently supports. You can't add, or remove, values from this list. A supported language includes default translations for all standard elements, including tabs, field labels, object names, Help text, and other elements, except for specific known language limitations (including Flow Designer). You'll probably want to contact support and ask for the process to request the language you'd like to see in the future.

Comment: if I create a picklist field on a custom or standard object, can I use the available languages to be displayed there?